# When and how did the criminal sense of 'grooming' arise?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

In a recent CNBC article on Ghislaine Maxwell they say:

> *Sternheim wrote of Maxwell, who is accused of crimes related to allegedly* *recruiting and grooming underage girls who later were sexually abused by* *eccentric investment advisor Jeffrey Epstein,...*

Looking up which sense of *groom* is meant in the article I found the following definition, probably a legal one, in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/groom):

> **groom** verb [T] (CRIME)
>
> to become friends with a child with the intention of trying to persuade the child to have a sexual relationship.

The above sense does not appear to  be related to the more common usage of groom:
looking up its origin in [the Online Etymological Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/groom)  provides no clear information on where the above usage may have come from.

So how and when did *groom* evolved into a criminal  act? Is it an AmE usage?

Comment: As per [this journal](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0886260517742048?journalCode=jiva) (On the Origin of Grooming): 'Over 40 years ago, professionals used 
the terms *sexual abuse, sexual assault, sexual misuse*, and *sexual molestation*
interchangeably, they still do today.
The concept of grooming has gained significant popularity in the last two 
decades'. [...] 'In the service of preserving the historical context of the term 
*grooming,* Ken Lanning, one of the first if not the first to use the term, 
searched back through his files for his use of the term.'

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - interesting,   but why grooming? Why is   grooming associated with the idea of sexual  abuse?

Comment: I don't know that's why I posted that as a 'comment'.

Comment: I could imagine someone grooming a bank employee to take part in fraud; no sex necessarily involved, underage or otherwise.

Comment: For clarification, 'grooming' doesn't have a primary sense of criminality, but it has one (of meany senses) associated with 'preparing to be a victim' by collocation. It is not a legal term at all.

Comment: @KannE reference?

Comment: Just in case the commenters are interested in facts, 'grooming', used with the specific sense "persuasion, inducement, enticement, or coercion for the purpose of  any sexual activity for which any person can be charged with a criminal offense, or attempts to do so", most definitely is against a number of laws. At the federal level, for example, it is a violation of 18 U.S. Code § 2422. Numerous state laws are modeled on the federal law.

Comment: @kanne I've never watched oprah

Answer (score 36):

It almost certainly comes from slightly older senses of groom, meaning to tend and prepare.

In the words of the OED, "groom" can mean:

> To tend or attend to carefully; to give a neat, tidy, or ‘smart’ appearance to.

and more relevantly:

> To prepare as a political candidate; in extended use, to prepare or coach for a career, a sporting contest, etc. Originally U.S.

The former is traced to 1843, and their examples of the latter go back to 1887. The source of this idiom is obviously from grooming a horse, which means to tend, feed, brush, and look after an animal.

The OED has a draft addition under the entry for groom *v.*

> Of a paedophile: to befriend or influence (a child), now esp. via the internet, in preparation for future sexual abuse.

This goes back to 1985:

> Chicago Tribune 28 May v. 8/2   These ‘friendly molesters’ become acquainted with their targeted victim.., gaining their trust while secretly grooming the child as a sexual partner.

They don't give a specific description of how the meaning has shifted but it seems reasonable to suppose it has gone from meaning to tend and prepare a horse for use, to meaning to tend and prepare a human being for a purpose.

["groom, v.". OED Online. December 2020. Oxford University Press.  (accessed February 17, 2021)](https://www-oed-com.nls.idm.oclc.org/view/Entry/81721?rskey=zGmOb7&result=3&isAdvanced=false).

Comment: "dictionaries note that it's been used for more than a century to mean preparing a successor, or coaching someone for a career or contest" [When did groom become dirty bbc.co.uk](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/magazine/7758292.stm)

Comment: Given the OED asserts a US origin, it seems the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groom) definition is relevant here: "to get into readiness for a specific objective".  And it's in standard current use e.g. ski slopes and ice rinks are 'groomed' for use.

Comment: @JimmyJames - yes, but I guess there is a  considerable difference between  preparing for something and preparing for sexual abuse. May be grooming has some  nuance about it.

Comment: @Gio I'm pretty sure 'sexual abuse' is 'something'.  If you want to more more precise, it's an 'activity' and 'groom' is typically used to refer to preparing something for an activity. 
People are 'groomed' for management.  Perhaps this usage is primarily US/Canadian English.  This doesn't seem mysterious at all to me.  Even if the usage hadn't become common, I would understand the meaning.

Comment: "Grooming" itself is neutral - whether it's positive or negative depends on what someone is being groomed for, or for what purpose.  Grooming someone for a top slot in a corporation - good, grooming someone to be amenable to sexual manipulation and control - bad.   I'm unaware of any nuance about "grooming" that makes it bad. Pretty sure it's the clear negative purpose of some sorts of grooming that makes those sorts of grooming bad.

Comment: I wonder if the 1985 date is also when the _concept_ emerged. We thought of child molesters as strangers who yanked them into a van. But possibly, around the 1980's, we began to realize it was often someone known and trusted, and this able to "groom".

Comment: @JimmyJames - yes, abuse is “something”  but it appears to be the first and only derogatory sense regarding  the connotation  of preparing someone for something. And that is just from the 80s. Curious, is it?

Comment: @Gio I found [this 1948 essay](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1948/01/death-pig/309203/) by E. B. White which contains the following: "I had assumed that there could be nothing much wrong with a pig during the months it was being groomed for murder;"  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JimmyJames - well, “groomed for murder” clearly means prepared for murder. But “grooming an underage girl” has the implicit nuance of abuse in it. In that respect grooming has  developed  a specific   connotation. If you say “prepare an underage girl” you would probably ask “for what”?

Comment: @Gio I feel like you've gotten your answer.  Around the 80s the phrase became used in this context and now it's the most common usage.  The point I was making is that this wasn't some sort of corruption.  It already had the meaning 'to prepare'.  There was no change in meaning, just more of a specialization.

Comment: @JimmyJames - yes, now I know when, but not really why grooming developed that sense and prepare or other synonyms didn’t. In the OED older examples cited above there is actually no hint at a usage in a “negative” sense. I realize we are discussing about fine shades of meaning, and probably there is no correct answer, but this is what ELU is or should be about.

Comment: This 'answer' is a speed bump. *OED*, being a historical dictionary, is not a good source to underpin a real answer. The sense of 'to groom' questioned is easily found in the popular press prior to 1985, and in specialist literature much earlier. This thinly veiled regurgitation of *OED* material, as it stands, is more an avoidance of the question than an answer.

Comment: @Gio All the meanings of the verb "groom" connote "smoothing things out" by removing unwanted stuff - tangles from a dog's coat, branches from a hiking trail, a political candidate's propensity for gaffes, etc. In the sexual abuse meaning, the abuser makes the victim trust them to reduce the likelihood that their interactions will be reported to parents/authorities and to make the victim more likely to follow the abuser's directions. "Prepare" and its synonyms don't carry this connotation of smoothing things out. That's my theory for why groom gained this meaning and the other words didn't.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the final question:

> Is it an AmE usage?

No, it's not just North American - it's well understood in Britain as well, without need for any adjective in context (as in your sample).

I have two Oxford dictionaries to hand: ODE (3rd ed, 2010) lists this meaning (as part of the sense *to prepare or train* someone), though my slightly older SOED (5th ed, 2002) does not.

Answer (score 0):

"Grooming" has multiple meanings. In the context of career, the meaning is metaphorical of improving appearance. In the context of sexual abuse, I believe it is drawn more from that of primate social interaction. Grooming among primates appears to have many functions, including as a prelude to coitus, but all of them relate to social cohesion. So as it relates to sexual abuse, it is any action that establishes or advances the (inappropriate) relationship.

Comment: This is all well and good but the question is about *the **history** of this usage*

Comment: Aside from not providing sources, and not making explicit connections, this answer provides a brilliant insight into the history of the development of the sense of 'to groom' in question.

Comment: @JEL - yes, a real pity they don't cite any source.